# How to properly close Word documents after Documents.Open

Tags: ms-word, office-interop, office-automation, document-processing

I have the following code for a C# console app. It parses a Word document for textboxes and inserts the same text into the document at the textbox anchor point with markup. This is so I can convert to Markdown using `pandoc`, including textbox content which is not available due to https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3086. I can then replace my custom markup with markdown after conversion.

The console app is called in a PowerShell loop for all documents in a target list.

When I first run the Powershell script, all documents are opened and saved (with a new name) without error. But the next time I run it, I get an occasional popup error:

> The last time you opened '' it caused a serious error. Do you still want to open it?

I can get through this by selecting yes on every popup, but this requires intervention and is tedious and slow. I want to know why this code results in this problem?

```cs
string path = args[0];

Console.WriteLine($"Parsing {path}");

Application word = new Application();
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(path);

try
{

    foreach (Shape shp in doc.Shapes)
    {
        if (shp.TextFrame.HasText != 0)
        {
            string text = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
            int page = shp.Anchor.Information[WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber];
            string summary = Regex.Replace(text, @"\r\n?|\n", " ");
            Console.WriteLine($"++++textbox++++ Page {page}: {summary.Substring(0, Math.Min(summary.Length, 40))}");

            string newtext = @$"{Environment.NewLine}TEXTBOX START%%%{text}%%%TEXTBOX END{Environment.NewLine}";

            var range = shp.Anchor;
            range.InsertBefore(Environment.NewLine);
            range.Collapse();
            range.Text = newtext;
            range.set_Style(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal);
        }
    }

    string newFile = Path.GetFullPath(path) + ".notb.docx";
    doc.SaveAs2(newFile);
}
finally
{
    doc.Close();
    word.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The console app is called in a PowerShell loop for all documents in a target list.

You can automate Word from your PowerShell script directly without involving any other dependencies. At least that will allow you to keep a single Word instance without creating each time a new Word `Application` instance for each document:

```
Application word = new Application();
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(path);
```

In the loop you could just open documents for processing and then closing them. It should improve the overall performance of your solution.

When you are done processing a document you need to close it by using the [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.close(method)) method which closes the specified document.

Also when a new Word `Application` instance is created, don't forget to close it as well by calling the [Quit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.quit(method)) method which quits Microsoft Word and optionally saves or routes the open documents.

```
Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, OriginalFormat:=wdWordDocument
```